# Why is `TableCell`'s `tableRow` property not generic?

Tags: generics, javafx, tableview

Looking at [`TableCell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableCell.html) we can see it has properties for its table view, column and row, but while the `TableView` and `TableColumn` properties are generic, the one for `TableRow` is a raw type, which forces you to cast unnecessarily if you want to use it.

Is there a technical reason for this? Is this an oversight by the designers of JavaFX? A bug perhaps?

Comment: hmm... isnt that fixed in fx9? Remember that there was some debate (and a rfe? memory is frail ;-)

Comment: I couldn't find any relevant discussion on the openjfx mailing list, nor any relevant bug reports. If you can find any please share the link. But it seems you are correct - the Java 9 [documentation](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/TableCell.html#tableRowProperty) has it generic.

Comment: yeah, found it as well - and the associated bug report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8144088 - indeed marked as fixed