# Javafx: TableCell getTableRow

Tags: java, generics, javafx, tablecell, raw-types

I was wondering why do the `TableCell`'s `getTableRow()` method has no Generic while Table cell has, and it is pretty obvious that the return type would be the same that the cell's generic defines. So let take and example:

I have a class:

```
class MyCustomCell<S extends MyType, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if(empty){
            setText(null);
        }else {
            S data = (S) getTableRow().getItem();
            // do something with data.
        }
    }
}
```

First of all I have to cast it to `(S)`, and there is a warning: 
*Unchecked cast: java.lang.Object. Reason: 'getTableRow()' has raw type, so result of getItem is erased*. But why? For example at the `TreeTableCell` this works fine the method there is:

`public final TreeTableRow<S> getTreeTableRow() { return treeTableRow.get(); }`

so you don't event have to cast it to `(S)`. I was researching a little bit and I found this: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8096461, but neither this link and  the javadoc of the respective method, don't say anything for me. That bug's resolution is also set to Won't fix, but I cannot understand why, or why was this developed this way, without generic. Can you explain me or give something that I can use for understanding it?

Comment: It was most likely an oversight, but it is fixed in Java 9. See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553948/why-is-tablecells-tablerow-property-not-generic  and the linked JDK bug report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8144088

Comment: Ah okay, but it seems java 9 is a little bit  far away from us, it is so sad that we have to use that as it is.Thanks for the comment and sorry for duplicate Idk why I didn't find that question.